# How to specify shapefile variables length in R?

Tags: shapefile, r

I am using R to edit some shapefiles with `readOGR` and `writeOGR` functions. I can edit the name and type of my shapefile variables, but not the length.

Example: i want that my variable of type string takes a length of 20. For now it takes the default length of 80 (i visualize the shapefile under QGIS).

Any hint ?

Comment: Not sure if that is strictly a duplicate answer, since the solution there shrinks string fields to the smallest it needs to be. If you really want to set it to exactly 20 (or some other number) then add a comment and we can re-open.

Comment: It is not really what i am looking for. This works but it shrinks only string fields + it takes the smallest it needs to be as you said, but based on actual values. However, i may need to put larger values later..

Comment: Hmmm okay there may be other ways to be more precise... I'll have a think and meanwhile the Q is open again...